# Queue a Windows service if already running

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I'm developing a Windows Service that will run every 15 minutes, and sends out push notifications to iOS, Android, and BlackBerry users. Each of these device specific operations will run in separate threads in the Windows service. That's all well and good, but there is a chance that we will need to send out up to 50,000 push notifications at a time. If this happens, it could possibly take more than 15 minutes, so before it's time for the next service to run, I want to know if the previous process has finished, and if it hasn't, wait and queue the Windows service to execute once the prior execution is complete. I'm fine with the threading aspect, but I don't know the correct way to implement the scenario that I've described above. Is there some sort of "Wait" or "Queue" mechanism in C#?

Comment: A service typically runs continually - Is your service an actual windows service, or just a process setup via Task Scheduler, or something else?

Comment: It is an actual Windows service, but I'm open to doing this through another manner, if a Windows service can't handle my use case.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the Windows service has a timer, and although it's running continually, it will only execute the logic every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Since your service is using a `Timer` to schedule the work, it can always disable the timer when work begins, and reschedule, as needed, at the end of your work.

This allows a lot of flexibility.  If a queue of work took more than 15 minutes, you could decide whether to delay the next one, just start it immediately (potentially running "forever"), skip it entirely, or whatever you needed, as the timer won't run again until it was reenabled.